# Setting a loader before component loads

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to only show the `CircularProgress` loader when the `products` have not been loaded yet. Without loading, the code shows the empty state from `else`. I need to add the loader so that the `CircularProgress` shows before `products` loads in instead of the empty state. Currently receiving a runtime error at `const data = await products();`

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  let products;
    
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const data = await products();
          if (data) {
            setLoading(false);
          }
          setLoading(true);
        })();
      }, []);
    
      {
        loading && <CircularProgress/>;
      }
      if (props.productList && props.productList.length > 0) {
        products = props.productList.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            item.status === 1 && (
              <Col key={index}>
                <Product
                  {...item}/>
              </Col>
            )
          );
        });
      } else {
        products = (
          {...empty state}
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function call (or one that returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)), not a variable (if its value is not a `Promise`).

In your case, you could just display your `<CircularProgress/>` in your `else` block:

```
  if (props.productList && props.productList.length > 0) {
    return props.productList.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        item.status === 1 && (
          <Col key={index}>
            <Product
              {...item}/>
          </Col>
        )
      );
    });
  } else {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CircularProgress/>;
        {/* empty display... */}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```

Note that you do not seem to have a criterion to differentiate between *loading* and *not loading but empty* states, hence here I put both loading and empty displays together.

If you want to separate them, you could use a 3rd type for your `productList` prop, which would let you add a 3rd `else if` block; typically:

- `null` for loading (initial state)
- `[]` for no longer loading, but empty
- `[ ... ]` (length > 0) no longer loading and not empty

```
// In parent component that fetches data
const [productList, setProductList] = useState(null); // Initial state null before data is loaded

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData() // Your data retrieving function
    .then((data) => setProductList(data)); // Assuming data is ALWAYS an array, possibly empty
}, []);

// In component that displays the list
if (props.productList === null) {
  // Data is still loading
  return <CircularProgress/>;

} else if (props.productList.length === 0) {
  // Data is loaded but empty
  return {/* empty display... */};

} else {
  // Data is loaded and not empty
  return <React.Fragment>
    { productList.map((item, index) => {/* etc. */}) }
  </React.Fragment>;
}
```

Depending on how you actually fetch your `productList` data, you may also have an explicit `loading` flag, that you could use as a separate prop.

Comment: I have an empty state block to show when productList.length < 0. So I need to show the a loader before products load, but still allow the empty state to show when productList.length < 0

Comment: Then simply display both! Do you need help on that as well?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to React. I only want to display the loader before products load, and the empty state if there are no products in the list

Comment: There isn't a `data` array, I added it as a variable to represent the data inside of the `productList`. The data (i.e the products in the productList) comes from the `productList`.

Comment: Hum seems like you need more basic training and experience before attempting this task... I wish you good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You want to set your initial `loading` state to 'true':

```js
// Change:
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

// To:
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

The problem is that you set it initially to `false`, so on first load it will not show the `<CircularProgress />` component.

Your effect:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const data = await products();
      if (data) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
      setLoading(true);
    })();
  }, []);
```

is an async IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), with no dependencies meaning:

- It is called on initial render only (without updating when props change)
- Any code **after** the `await` will not execute until `await products();` has resolved.

This means that essentially `loading` is `false` (the initial value set in `useState(false)`) **until** the `products();` function resolves or rejects. If it is generally going to contain data, this means that the state will not show any loading, at all. The only time it will show loading is if your `products();` call fails (does not contain `data`) in which case the `setLoading(false)` call will set it to false and the `<CircularProgress/>;` component will display.

To go over your current code (assuming it is the content of a functional component):

```js
// Functional component definition
const MyComponent = () => {
  // State store, initially set to 'false', meaning that until changed, the value of `loading` === false
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // Side effect function - runs once on load, and then never again 
  (as dependency array is empty)
  useEffect(() => {
    // Define an async IIFE. This code will immediately execute when 
    the component loads, and then never again.
    (async () => {
      // await here will wait for the 'products' function to 
      'resolve' or 'reject' before continuing on to the next line...
      const data = await products();
      // By this point, 'loading' has been stuck on 'false' until 
      'products' has resolved/rejected.
      if (data) {
        // Data is returned, we are no longer 'loading'
        setLoading(false);
      }
      // Data is not returned and we should set `loading` to `true`
      setLoading(true);
    })();
  }, []);

  // There should be a `return` here e.g: `return loading ?
  // '{COMPONENT_TO_SHOW_WHEN_LOADING}' : 
  // '{COMPONENT_TO_SHOW_WHEN_LOAD_COMPLETE}'
  // Otherwise this code is fine, providing that `loading` is set correctly while awaiting the `data` from the `products()` function.
  {
    loading && <CircularProgress/>;
  }
  if (props.productList && props.productList.length > 0) {
    products = props.productList.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        item.status === 1 && (
          <Col key={index}>
            <Product
              {...item}/>
          </Col>
        )
      );
    });
  } else {
    products = (
      {...empty state}
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are facing is the architecture problem. You are awaiting for `products` to load and changing the `loading` states but you are not using the `data` anywhere in the code !!!

#### Your approach

###### State:

```
loading => true
   After data = products() => loading false
```

###### Component:

```
if loading => show Loader

if props               |
       show ...        |
else                   |   This block is not dependent on the data loaded
       show ...        |
```

#### Right approach

###### State:

```
loading => true
   After data = products() => loading false
```

###### Component:

```
if loading => show Loader

if data                |
       show ...        |
else                   |   This block is should be data dependent not props dependent
       show ...        |
```

##### Some suggested changes.

1. ```
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);  Initially it should be true not false
   ```
2. Change your approach from

   ```
   loading && <Loader/>

   if props.length>0               
          show Component 1        
   else                   
          show Component 2
   ```

   to

   ```
   loading ? <Loader/> : props.length > 0 ? show Component 1 : show Component 2
   ```

---

##### Edit

Suggestion in terms of code snippets

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const data = await products();
      if (data) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
      setLoading(true);
    })();
  }, []);

  
    {loading ? <CircularProgress/> : (props.productList && props.productList.length > 0) ? 
    products = props.productList.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        item.status === 1 && (
          <Col key={index}>
            <Product
              {...item}/>
          </Col>
        )
      );
    })
   : 
    products = (
      {...empty state}
    );
```

Comment: Are you able to put your suggestions into a code snippet that follows the structure of the question? I don't see where we use setLoading in your answer

Comment: I have updated my question based on your demand, hope it helps

Comment: Getting a formatting error using the code snippet

Comment: you'll have to play around with common and curly brackets ,try the edited code. And try to make some bracket changes to remove the formatting errors

Comment: unexpected token at `products = props`

Comment: Try the following changes, it is very hard to guide you from here, either produce reproducible code or refer https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_conditional_rendering.asp#:~:text=Another%20way%20to%20conditionally%20render%20a%20React%20component,render%20elements%20is%20by%20using%20a%20ternary%20operator and try make changes with your own self

Comment: Same error. I feel like this would be the right answer, but something wrong with the formatting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250772/discussion-between-krishna-acharya-and-kyle-underhill).

Comment: I have updated the code and sent the link via github file. Let me know if solves your problem